# Space required for Golang interface

Tags: go

How much space (in bytes) does a Golang interface take up?

For example, which would take up more space?

```golang
type Stringer interface { String() string }

strSlice := make([]string, 4)
stringerSlice := make([]Stringer, 4)
```

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/z_3D6tn2yn

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- interface consumes 2 words of memory: 1 word for runtime type and 1 word for data pointer;
- string consumes 2 words of memory: 1 word for base pointer and 1 word for length;
- slice consumes 3 words of memory: 1 word for base pointer, 1 word for length and 1 word for capacity;
- function, channel and map consume 1 word.

Based on the machine type(32bit or 64bit) word size is 4 bytes length or 8 bytes length respectively.

Answer (score 2):

Interace is a structure of 2 words:

- pointer to data
- pointer to itab - table of methods.

So at 64-bit machine: it will take 8*2=16 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

**Interface** consumes 2 words of memory: 1 word for runtime type and 1 word for data pointer.
**Interfaces** are ***Pointer to data***, ***Pointer to itab - table of methods***.

**String** consumes 2 words of memory: 1 word for base pointer and 1 word for length
**Slice** consumes 3 words of memory: 1 word for the base pointer, 1 word for length and 1 word for capacity.
**Function**, channel and map consume 1 word.

Based on the machine type(**32bit** or **64bit**) word size is 4 bytes length of 8 bytes length respectively.